# Does there always exist a reversible path between two states?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

For a reversible process it holds that $dS=\delta Q/T$. We thus get the fundamental relation of thermodynamics: $dS=dU/T+P/T dV$. The reasoning goes that because entropy is a state function, this relation holds even for irreversible processes because we can imagine that there is a reversible path between the two states.

But how do we know there exists a reversible path between two given states?

Answer (score 3):

There is not just one reversible path between the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states of a system.  There are an infinite number of reversible paths, and they all give the exact same value for the change in entropy (as well as for the changes in the other thermodynamic functions).  The integral of $dq/T_{boundary}$ for all these paths is also greater than the corresponding integral for any irreversible path, where $T_{boundary}$ is the temperature at the boundary between the system and its surroundings.  This is known as the Clausius inequality.

Comment: My question.is WHY does there exist a reversible path.

Comment: Why would't there be one?

Comment: Why don't you pose an irreversible process for me, and I'll see if I can devise a reversible process between the same two end states?

Comment: We can't have any fruitful discussion without clarifying what your definition of "reversible path" is.

Comment: @Blue Various You first.  What is your definition?

Comment: I personally believe that defining a reversible process probably only makes sense for adiabatic processes or cycle.  If I'm forced to define it in general;
A reaction C, which changes the state of System X from A to B, is a reversible process if (i) there exists an opposite reaction path C', (ii) both C and C' can be defined as a smooth curve in the state space, and (iii) after one revolution through C→C', System X itself and the external system interacting with it return to their original state.

Comment: Are you referring to a chemical reaction, or something else?

Comment: For now, I'm limiting my discussion to only systems that can be specified by U, V, and N; this includes  typical piston movements.

Comment: Since we consider a system in which U, V, and N can be specified, we can define a new state $\delta Q_{rev}$ in the following way; $\delta Q_{rev}:=dU+P dV + \mu dN$. The $\delta Q_{rev}$ is clearly a state quantity※, but it is not necessarily a closed form.※ Here, a state quantity is a physical quantity that is uniquely determined by the state of the system alone and does not depend on the past history or path.

Comment: For above state quontity $\delta Q_{rev}$,
If the state space is mathmatically simply-connected and $T>0$, then following two statements are equivalent;
(1) ${S_e}(U,V,N)$ exists and that $dS_{e}(U,V,N)=Q_{rev}/T$
(2)$\delta Q_{rev}/T$ is a closed form.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  Maybe some other responder can help you.

Comment: On the other hand, the heat $\delta Q$ that actually comes in during the reaction process is not necessarily a state quantity.　If "a reaction that can be drawn as a smooth curve in state space" is "δQ=δQ_rev at any point in its reaction path," then the reaction is probably reversible.
Also, even if the two states are connected by a reaction path that can be described as a smooth curve in state space, there is no guarantee that δQ=δQ_rev at any point on the reaction path. (Unless, perhaps, the system is completely closed.)

Comment: "Why would't there be one?" @ChetMiller Engineers might be happy with this kind of reasoning, but mathematicians will scratch your eyes out.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum. Hey, I'm not the one wasting my time  obsessing over this.  If that's what life is like as a mathematician, good luck with that.

Comment: I think the problem is that @BlueVarious was thinking of this in the most general abstract setting. I had possibly a similar problem with this, check this stack I asked on mathematics stack exchange [geometry of differential stuff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841412/geometrical-difference-between-exact-and-inexact-differentials)

Comment: I have a question myself actually, you claim there are infinite number of paths but suppose I instilled a constraint. Say, out of all the reversible paths between two states, I want an isothermal one, are there still infinite number of paths?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Are the two end states at the same temperature?  Maybe you can provide a specific example that we can focus on?

Comment: Sir, I have a question, is "reversible expansion work a state function"? I believe that the answer to this is yes, but I am having trouble thinking why this is so. According to me, we can have infinitely many reversible processes between two states (as you too state in this answer, but I feel @BlueVarious suggests there are not infinitely many such processes ). I think if it is correct that reversible expansion work is a state function, then yes, it would be the only one which is adiabatic work, because then $\Delta U=-W$ and since $U$ is a state function, hence would be $W$. [Continued]:

Comment: And if there are infinitely many reversible processes, in which we can carry out the expansion, then obviously, work would be different for different processes, therefore it won't be a state function...

Comment: Right.  Work and heat are not state functions.

Comment: @ChetMiller Sir, I know that work and heat are not state functions, they are path functions, but this is true in general. What I have said is, for reversible process. I am asking this again because this question was asked in an entrance exam and the key given to it stated that reversible expansion work is a state function. It is a reputed exam, so I want to be clear on this topic. [continued]:

Comment: For adiabatic process, work is a state function, right? because it's simply equal to the change in the internal energy, which is a state function...

Comment: A state function is not dependent on path.  For a non-adiabatic path between the same two end states, the work and heat are different.

Answer (score 3):

you can always construct a Carnot cycle passing through any two states(on P-V graph).
Of course, Carnot cycle consists of 4 reversible paths.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the Comment;

Can I understand your statement quoted below is same as Box 1 below?

> The reasoning goes that because entropy is a state function, this relation holds even for irreversible processes because we can imagine that there is a reversible path between the two states.

If so, all states shall be connectable by path, **but it is not necessary that the path is reversible**. In other words, as long as the path exists, everything is "ideal" in the sense of Box1.

> Box1:
>
> - To define entropy (exchanged entropy; $S_e$), for any two states A and B, there is at least one "ideal" path between A and B.
> - If $c_1$,$c_2$ are the "ideal" path between states A and B, then the following holds;
>   $$\int_{c_1} d{S_e} =\int_{c_2} d{S_e}$$

We call it a "quasi-static process" in which U, V ,N ,and ... are fixed at any stage of the reaction. This quasi-static process is used as a method to realize a path that can be considered as a curve in the (upper half of) Euclidean space.

- When we say that "entropy is a state quantity," that "entropy" is the exchange entropy.
- If the path were irreversible, then a new term, called generated entropy ($S_g$), will be generated. Clausius' inequality is not an equality if this generative entropy exists. Clausius' inequality is not an equality if this generative entropy exists.

Indeed as described [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/517292/is-ds-frac-delta-q-irevt-true-for-non-reversible-processes?rq=1), $\delta Q $ is path-dependent. But, U, V, N and T are state quantities and **your following equation is path-independent**

$${dS}_{e}=dU/T+P/T dV +\mu/T dN$$

and if we define the new state quantity  $\delta Q_{rev}$, the   $\delta Q_{rev}$

$$\delta Q_{rev}=dU+P dV +\mu dN$$

then, the $\delta Q_{rev}/T$ is a closed form and having a potential.

So once we admit that $dS_e$ can be written as the above equation, whether the curve is of a reversible process or not, as long as we keep track of U, V, N, and T from time to time, we can "recover" the function $S_e$ even if we don't know the so-called $\delta Q$ itself, IMO.

> But, it **would be simpler to make it an axiom that there is something called "exchange entropy"**.

Comment: Great answer! I'm happy that you went into entropy generation..most people skip it and it causes much confusion

Answer (score 1):

> The reasoning goes that because entropy is a state function, this relation ($dS=dU/T+P/TdV$) holds even for irreversible processes because ...

Well, this premise is wrong because an irreversible process goes through out-of-equilibrium states for which state variables such as *T* or *P* might not even be defined at the scale of the system, and such out-of-equilibrium states are out of the scope of (equilibrium) thermodynamics. That's actually why one needs to find reversible paths to be able to compute overall changes between two *equilibrium** states.

* Indeed, for a reversible path to exist between two given states, all the intermediate states must be *equilibrium* states, and thus all the more so for the initial and final states considered.

Now, I admit that this does not answer the question of whether there always exists a reversible path between any two equilibrium states.

Answer (score -2):

Its because the equation you mentioned Tds=dU + Pdv is now a point function and does not depend on the path. Although it is defined for a reversible process but its valid for all since it becomes a point function.[image]

Comment: In the real world there doesn't exist a reversible process...but we assume that all process are reversible because we cannot plot any irreversible process  on the thermodynamic coordinates

Comment: *we cannot plot any irreversible process* - quasi-static is sufficient to plot trajectories in thermodynamic phase space

Comment: How does your answer help with the question, which is about $dS$ not $Tds$?

Comment: This does not answer the question